# How to prevent regex handle inline code?

Tags: regex

I have got follow regex http://regexr.com/3gdgp

````
`([^`\n]+)`

header
`foo()` 
`bar()` some text
newline
thereis code:
```
void main()
{
    writeln(`hello world's`);
}
```
````

It select code in `writeln` block, because it use same quotes. But I do not need to select it. How to fix my regex?

I expect to select `foo()` and `bar()`

Comment: What are you desiring to be selected?

Answer (score 0):

For the sample text you show, just add the beginning-of-line anchor `^` and make sure the multiline switch is on.  For regexr.com that means choosing the multiline flag.  You did not specify the flavor of regex you're using, so you'll need to figure out how to specify that switch in your environment (unless it's on by default).

```
^`([^`\n]+)`
```

Comment: Nobody can guess where your foo() and bar() will appear. String literals can appear about anywhere in code, so **you need to specify precisely what format the header is in, or if there is any unique feature that delimits these strings differently from code**.  Once you define these, it's also best that you try crafting a better regex pattern yourself.  You may find that you need to first separate any preamble (i.e. header, non-code, etc.) from the main code using one process, then match additional details like foo() and bar() once that top text block is already separated from the code.